# data structure to find value for closest point to input data

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, nearest-neighbor

I have a dataset where I map a value to a three dimensional point. e.g. (1,2,3)->5; (2,4,1)->7; and so on.
I need to store these and be able to quickly find the desired value. If there were an entry for every possible input, I could just use an 3D array (or a dictionary), use the point as an index and do no searching at all.

The input however is real valued, so not every single point exists in the dataset. I want to find the n nearest points to the input data and get their related values to perform interpolation.
Which data structure could I use to implement this in an efficient way? The data structure only needs to be created once and does not have to change later.

Comment: *find value for closes point...* suggests a tree based structure probably a balanced one like red black.

Comment: The [KD-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Nearest_neighbour_search) supports efficient nearest neighbor searching.

Comment: do you need to find the closest point in Z^3 (only integers) given a point in R^3(real values)?

Comment: Can you say something about the distribution of data points? Different data structures work best on different distributions.

Comment: I need to find the point in R^3, the examples were probably bad, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a [K-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).
It is a data structure designed especially to partition points of a `k` dimensional space, and it allows to find the nearest neighbor to a given point remarkably fast (`O(log n)`).
You also probably won't need to implement a k-d tree yourself, since implementations of the structure exist in many languages (I used it in python, and I'd bet you can find solid implementations in most of the common languages).

Comment: As far as I see it the K-d-tree only stores the point itself. So after finding the nearest points, I would then use a different data structure (like a dictionary or hash-map) to find the values I associate to that points, right?

Comment: Yes, a hash map would do the job really well then, it's a fast and practical way to map keys to values.